# What is the source of this tty console output?

Tags: tty, x-server, getty, armbian

I'm making a kiosk system using Armbian on an orangepi zero 3. The kiosk is a on a local server that I connect to using chromium browser launched from my `~/.bash_profile`. Before chromium-browser starts up `getty@tty1.service` is launched and autologs in my user. When the getty terminal launches there's a line that prints and I can't seem to find the source. The line printed is `Armbian 23.08.0-trunk Jammy tty1`

I've tried changing `sysctl kernel.printk` to all zeros and `dmesg -n 1` but neither of these work.

Comment: I found text that was getting printed in /etc/issue and /etc/issue.net. I'm not sure what process was referencing those files but stopped the process from printing anything.

Comment: Traditionally, _/etc/issue_ is printed by some form of getty, such as [agetty](https://linux.die.net/man/8/agetty).